# Hide ImageView when orientation is chaged

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, android-imageview

I'm trying to hide(ImageView.Gone) an image on my layout when the phone in landscape mode. I've tried:

```
this.imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sheep_image);
    this.myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            editText.setHint("orientation changed");
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
            } else {
                imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };
```

xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sheep_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/pic"/>
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens, not even the hint of the EditText.

Comment: Normally the entire view hierarchy is rebuilt for the new orientation, and you can make changes based on the new orientation in onCreate() after you inflate your layout.  Is this not the case you're dealing with? Are you doing something special to prevent the usual behavior that happens with orientation changes?

Comment: I'm new to android programming, if I understand you correctly,  the onCreate() method is invoked on each orientation change?

Comment: By default, when you have a configuration change (such as an orientation change) your activity will be destroyed and recreated with the new configuration. This means all the views will be recreated in onCreate when you inflate them.  You can, at this moment, decide their visibility.  You can also have completely different layout for portrait and orientation that get selected automatically based on orientation at the time of inflation.